# Infinite loop in Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I see many questions about this but nothing from answers helps me to solve it. I wanted to see how `saga` works since I haven't worked with it.

Here is the code

```
export function* fetchItems() {
  try {
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_REQUEST })
    const response = yield call(fetch, 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const data = response.json();
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { items: data } })
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_FAILURE, payload: { error: error.message }})
  }
}
```

It calls an infinite loop, I tried a lot of things but nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, for `watchAsyncSagaFunction` generator function you need to create another constant that is different than the one that you call at the beginning of `asyncSagaFunction`.

Example:

```
export function* asyncSagaFunction() {
  try {
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_REQUEST })
    const response = yield call(fetch, 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const data = response.json();
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { items: data } })
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_FAILURE, payload: { error: error.message }})
  }
}
```

There is `ITEMS_FETCH_REQUEST`, you need to create another one, for example,`ITEMS_FETCH` and in a component call that one.

```
export function* watchAsyncSagaFunction() {
  yield takeLatest(ITEMS_FETCH, fetchItems)
}
```